# Django - NoReverseMatch no arguments not found at create view when initializing form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-errors

I'm trying to initialize a form with some data passed as parameters. I have already in the Model the *get_absolute_url* but I don´t believe the error is going that way, here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /payments/addtoexistingweek/1/2020-W07
Exception Value: Reverse for 'pagoaexistente' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['payments/addtoexistingweek/(?P<carro>[0-9]+)/(?P<semana>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

This is how I'm getting the parameters:

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' request.resolver_match.kwargs.carro request.resolver_match.kwargs.semana %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

> urls.py

```
path('payments/addtoexistingweek/<int:carro>/<slug:semana>',
         views.AgregarPagoSemana.as_view(), name='pagoaexistente'),
```

> views.py

```
class AgregarPagoSemana(CreateView):

    template_name = "AC/add_paymentexistingweek.html"
    model = Pagos
    form_class = AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AgregarPagoSemana, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['carro'] = self.kwargs.get('carro')
        kwargs['semana'] = self.kwargs.get('semana')
        return kwargs
```

> forms.py

```
class AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.carro = kwargs.pop('carro')
        self.semana = kwargs.pop('semana')
        super(AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        fields = ('carro', 'pago', 'fecha', 'semana', 'renta')
        widgets = {'fecha': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                   'semana': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'week'})
                   }
```

if the arguments are not being sent I don´t get why I see:

```
NoReverseMatch at /payments/addtoexistingweek/1/2020-W07
```

and I see the 2 parameters there

**Update**

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' carro=carro semana=semana %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

> views.py

```
class AgregarPagoSemana(CreateView):

    template_name = "AC/add_paymentexistingweek.html"
    model = Pagos
    form_class = AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'semana': self.kwargs['semana'],
            'carro': self.kwargs['carro'],
        })
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AgregarPagoSemana, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['carro'] = self.kwargs.get('carro')
        kwargs['semana'] = self.kwargs.get('semana')
        return kwargs
```

I wanted to add this little piece of the Traceback:

```
NoReverseMatch  
<class 'django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch'>
args[]
context [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'form': 
        <AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente bound=False, valid=False, fields= 
        (carro;pago;fecha;semana;renta)>, 'view': <AC.views.AgregarPagoSemana 
        object at 0x04FBF790>, 'semana': '2020-W07', 'carro': 1}]
current_app ''
kwargs{}
reverse <function reverse at 0x03BA0B70>
self <django.template.defaulttags.URLNode object at 0x04FA0170>
url ''
view_name 'pagoaexistente'
```

My assumption with the update it is getting the paramaters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finally got the solution, the problem was that in the form template the cancel button had an incorrect namespace, that was the issue that it couldn´t find a reverse match.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' request.resolver_match.kwargs.carro request.resolver_match.kwargs.semana %}><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
```

This url is expected to have keyword arguments not positional arguments. So you could do:

```
<a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' carro=request.resolver_match.kwargs.carro semana=request.resolver_match.kwargs.semana %}>
```

But that is really ugly. What I'd suggest doing is exposing `carro` and `semana` in the template's context from the view. That way you avoid the `request.resolver_match.kwargs` annoyance.

```
class AgregarPagoSemana(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'semana': self.kwargs['semana'],
            'carro': self.kwargs['carro'],
        })
        return context
```

Then your template can use:

```
    <a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' carro=carro semana=semana %}>
```

If you want to avoid that extra method on the view, you can make use of the instance of the view always being included in the context with:

```
    <a href={% url 'pagoaexistente' carro=view.kwargs.carro semana=view.kwargs.semana %}>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the 3 solutions and I'm still getting the NoReverseMatch, I think it is worth telling you the idea which is a user can make more than 1 payment to a rented car in a week, so the web page from where I'm getting the url parameters is filtered by a queryset and the idea was to use the same parameters in the url to add another payment, that said, i'm not sure if I'm even getting the parameter to pass it to AgregarPagoSemana, but in the traceback interactive view I see that response.render() the callback kwargs is showing: {'carro': 1, 'semana': '2020-W07'}

Comment: I get that with the 3 solutions you provided

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t explain my self correctly, I tried the get_context_data and I'm still getting the NoReverseMatch, is there a way to know in the traceback that the parameters are being sent to the view?

Comment: Yes, use django debug toolbar. https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/

Comment: ok, another question regarding this issue, if the error says that NoReverseMatch at /payments/addtoexistingweek/1/2020-W07, I see that 1 and 2020-W07, which are the arguments, are in the URL and are the parameters that I want to pass, I dont understand why the exception value says: Reverse for 'pagoaexistente' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) ?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the issue, the problem was that in the form template the URL in the cancel button was incorrect, that fixed the NoReverseMatch, the problem that I have now is that the form is not getting prefilled. Thanks!